# How do I resolve "HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error" on IIS7.0

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-applications, iis-7

What causes this error, how can I fix it?

> Detailed Error Information
>   Module IIS Web Core
>   Notification BeginRequest
>   Handler Not yet determined
>   Error Code 0x8007052e
>   Config Error Can not log on locally to C:\inetpub\wwwroot as user administrator with virtual directory password
>   Config File Unavailable (Config Isolation)
>   Requested URL http://192.168.0.3:80/
>   Physical Path C:\inetpub\wwwroot
>   Logon Method Not yet determined
>   Logon User Not yet determined

Config Source

```
<application path="/" applicationPool="PS-Extranet">
    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot" userName="administrator" password="[enc:AesProvider:PrISRz2ggJH4bV46ktObfCSh91Y/yF9pAoLmH7eCnj0=:enc]" />
</application>
```

Comment: The "real" error message is usually someplace on the page.  You should post the full content of the error page your getting if you want help with this question.

Comment: Just want to point something out for people doing a Google search and coming up with this question if it's not obvious: I am using VS2012 with IISExpress. I accidentally deleted the folder in c:/Users/[YOUR USER NAME]/MyDoocuments/MyWebsites/[THE WEBSITE]. It was an empty folder (which for some reason my brain said to delete). Once I restored it from the Recycle Bin all was well. Sorry for the comment, but it seemed better than an answer that was going to wind up at the bottom and possibly not seen. This is just an alternative if nothing else here works.

Comment: See if this works: (1) go into IIS manager, (2) open the Advanced Settings window for website, (3) set the Physical Path Credentials to the administrator user.

Comment: Take a look here as well http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webtopics/archive/2010/03/08/troubleshooting-http-500-19-errors-in-iis-7.aspx

Comment: I know its old post but this is what worked for me (Easy solution), I just closed and re-opened the visual studio and it worked. I had exact same error. When i checked my git command prompt i could see `.vs/config/applicationhost.config` file was changed and it had update virtual directory path.

Comment: I installed the .NET Core framework (https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2) . That was which solved my problem

Comment: For me nothing here worked. But I found the issue by myself: My aspx page / web.config ... was in the c:/Users/... folder. I fixed it by just moving it somewhere else. The User folder seems to have some strange permissons.

Comment: I found this helpful. However - CLOSED

Answer (score 167, accepted):

Looks like the user account you're using for your app pool doesn't have rights to the web site directory, so it can't read config from there.  Check the app pool and see what user it is configured to run as.  Check the directory and see if that user has appropriate rights to it.  While you're at it, check the event log and see if IIS logged any more detailed diagnostic information there.

Comment: correct bruce, had resolved this this morning, it appeared the systems admin guy changed the accounts passwords on the servers but omitted to change the user account login foir the virtual directory. It seems that the error showed overnight when the site had a period of inactivity, shutting down application process. Thanks for the answer

Comment: For me it was the IT-department, that have changed the password on the  service account.

Comment: @Bruce: I am working on localhost and getting the same error.what to do in these case

Comment: The accepted answer to this question is a good one, addressing something commonly causes trouble, but for those of us that are experiencing a more obscure problem, Jomy John's answer currently has more votes. It concerns the <rewrite> tag in the web.config file. I'm commenting on it because it's a long way down the page, and I almost missed it.

Comment: @ChadMcGrath Pro tip:  Sort answers by votes (the setting will stick)

Comment: I fixed it by enabling Windows Authentication for the project in addition to anonymous authentication. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 469):

I had the same issue, but reason was different.

In my web.config there was a *URL rewrite module rule* and I haven’t installed URL rewrite module also. After I install [url rewrite module](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite) this problem solved.

Comment: +1000 completely asinine error message for having a config section it doesn't understand

Comment: @ChrisMarisic -- yes and no. The error message isn't directly helpful but it is correct. No url rewrite module so no <urlRewrite> config section is valid so the config is malformed technically. Now why they can't just spit out a better error is beyond me.

Comment: wow, 3 hours of time wasted.  I'll give it +1000000.   How ridiculous is that error message.   This saved my day.

Comment: The thing that's inexcusable about this error message is that when it shows the config source it shows (at least on mine) a blank window with code lines "-1" and "0". What it should show is the "<rewrite>" part in your config, screaming at you that it doesn't know what it is...

Comment: I wish Microsoft had a face so I could punch it for the useless error message.

Comment: This was my issue, but was convinced it wasn't this, I commented out the rules in the web.config and I got the same error weirdly, but when I installed the module my website worked so it was exactly this issue.

Comment: wow microsoft, another swing and miss

Comment: +1000 man! I thought application pools has this error but it is not. I have  commented out a rewrite element and the error goes away. Many thanks.

Comment: Mine was a similar issue - was a production web.config I was trying to get running locally and it had some redirects that weren't supported locally - error really didn't match the problem

Comment: guys this is the right solution most of the time!

Comment: it's not a direct answer, but it is the most possible reason that causes the issue for developers!!

Comment: This solved my case, although I don't have that tag in the web.config

Comment: Thanks a lot man , tried googling nothing found useful than this!!

Comment: Still valid solution on Win 11 and ASP .NET 4.8 Web App

Answer (score 138):

On Windows 10 I had to install `ASP.NET 3.5` and `ASP.NET 4.6` under `Internet Information Services` (the other boxes automatically check themselves):

[image]

Comment: This was the beginning solution for me in getting DNN working as an application, appose to a virtual directory, with a "classic" appPool setup.  Now I can run PHP and ASPX applications in IIS.  Thanks for starting the fire.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried so many solutions but no luck and i scrolled down here and tried your suggested solution and it worked for me. Good job #joshcomley

Comment: And this here is why you need to read ALL the suggested answers! Thank you Josh!

Comment: THANK YOU! I was getting a useless "HTTP Error 500" message on a new server I was configuring. In the logfile, I also saw a sc-substatus of 19 and a sc-win32-status of 33. Adding these dev features fixed mine.

Comment: that was the issue thank you!

Comment: Thank you! On Win Server 2012 I needed to install .NET 4.5 and ASP 4.5

Answer (score 82):

Finally I get the solution for my problem. The asp.net account not appear in the IIS manager because I didn't check its check Box in IIS to do this in windows 7 follow the steps

1. Open control panel
2. Click on” program” link (not uninstall programs)
3. Click” turn windows features on/off” link
4. locate” Internet Information services IIS” in the pop up window and expand its node
5. Expand the” World Wide Web Service” node
6. Expand “Application Development Features” node
7. check the check box of”ASP.NET”
8. Then click ok button

Now you will see the Asp.net account on the IIS manager and by default you see IIS account Now you should move you asp.net website from “my document” to another place the IIS have permission to access it (to any partition on your computer) Now browse your website from IIS manager and it should work.

Comment: This totally worked for me! Thanks! My problem was that ASP, ASP.NET 3.5 and ASP.NET 4.5 wasn't enabled. So I checked/enabled them and it works now thanks!

Answer (score 72):

We got this error after having to change our domain administrator password.

After monkeying with several settings, I eventually found that in the application in below path as it was set to specifically use the domain administrator account rather than pass-through authentication (who knows why).

> IIS Manager -> Basic Settings -> Connect

Comment: Fixed my issue also (was set to run as a user that we had disabled, so we switched back to pass-through).

Comment: I know this answer is old, but this solved my problem too.

Answer (score 21):

you need to do one step:

```
run->cmd

run "c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i"
```

Thats it

Comment: Run This command As a Administrator

Comment: On Windows 10 it gives following error:
This option is not supported on this version of the operating system.  Administrators should instead install/uninstall ASP.NET 4.5 with IIS8 using the "Turn Windows Features On/Off" dialog,  the Server Manager management tool, or the dism.exe command line tool.  For more details please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=216771.
Finished installing ASP.NET (4.0.30319.0) without changing existing web applications to use this version of ASP.Net.

Comment: Better ...if you could give a bit of explanation for this command.

Comment: no, that's not it

Answer (score 16):

Experienced this issue today and resolved it. Someone had set the "Path Credentials" for the "Default web site" in IIS to run as a specific user. This same user changed her password either due to the password expiring or just a routine change. Setting the "Default website" to connect as the "Application User" via the basic settings option resolved it for me

Comment: This was it for me.  Thanks!  My Path Credentials were set to my account, but earlier this evening I fat fingered my password and got locked out for 15 minutes.  Redoing my Path Credentials username/password did the trick.  Hmmm, since my account was unlocked, it occurs to me that if I had just bounced the service, that might have done the trick to.  Anyhoo, thanks!

Comment: It's Feb 2015, and IIS errors are as baffling as always. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

you probably change your NT password.

> Open IIS -> Right click on your application -> manage application -> advanced Setting -> physical path credentials.

good luck

Answer (score 11):

For me, I needed to enable **Http Activation** under the .Net features in "Add/Remove Windows Features"

Comment: This saved my couple of hours

Answer (score 10):

In my case, this error appears after changing folder's solution.

I solve the problem by goin to my project properties and recreate my virtual directory.

**Right click on project > Properties > Web > Under Servers section click "Create Virtual Directory"**

It will display a message saying that the virtual directory was created in another place and it will change it

Answer (score 6):

Got this working alright but not based on suggestions above. My case is that am getting the 500 error running iis7 on a windows 2008 server in a domain. Just added a new user in the domain and basically allow read/execute access to the virtual directory or folder. Ensure that the virtual folder>basic settings> Connect As > Path credentials is set to a user with read/xecute access. You can test settings and both authentication and authorization should work. Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

**Default web site** need to manage as well:

1 .On Default web site ->  basicSettings -> connect as, change it to the right user.

2.change the Identiy of the applicationPool that related to the defaultWebSite

g.luck

Answer (score 5):

Right now i had this error and resolved it. Your url could match with created virtual directory.

You have to check virtual directories, in my example i found in `applicationhost.config` next row:

```
<application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
    <virtualDirectory path="/admin/roles" physicalPath="C:\..." />
</application>
```

I tried to open page with an url (`http://localhost/admin/roles`) of `AdminController` and `Roles` action and got this error.

Answer (score 4):

For others out there, I got a similar error message due to trying to run a .Net 4 app in a .Net 2 app pool. Changing the .Net FX version for the app pool fixed it for me.

Answer (score 4):

I was having a similar error installing php 5.3.3 with the Error Code 0x80070020 with a direction to a few lines in web.config in my www root directory (not the standard root directory).

The solution, while crude, worked perfectly. I simply deleted the web.config file and now everything works. I spent HOURS trying other solutions to no avail.

If anyone thinks this was stupid, please let me know. If anyone else has spent the same amount of time pulling out hair, try it and see (after backing up the file of course)

Regards FEQ

Answer (score 4):

Was having the same error and fixing the credentials in the IIS app pool did not help.  I finally resolved the error in IIS by selecting my website under Default Web Site, Advanced Settings->Physical Path Credentials->Specific User, and reentered the credentials for the app pool user, then restarted IIS and the error went away and my website came up successfully.

Comment: yeah, likewise. iis7.5 on 2008R2. had to change the password due to local account complexity rules and didn't know it was also used in IIS. tracked it down with this comment and a coupe of others on here. but this one most specific.

Answer (score 3):

As I got the 500.19, I gave `IIS_IUSRS` full access rights for the mentioned web.config and for the folder of the project. This solved the issue.

You can give permissions by

1. right click on the folder / file
2. selecting the tab "security"
3. add the user `IIS_IUSRS` - don't forget the i in front of USRS and don't write an "e" as in USERS

Answer (score 3):

If it's bigin when you try to acces to joomla administrator panel, Just a username and password problem  !! You have just to update a jos_user in your joomla database.

Go to your joomla web site directory and open a **configuration.php** with bloc note or note pad to show what database name your joomla administrator site use. 
You have to find a line who have:

```
public $user = 'joomlauser251';           //MySQL username
```

In my case `joomlauser251` is my DB name.

Login to your mysql:

```
 mysql -uyourusername -pyourpassword
```

Select database for your joomla:

```
use joomlauser251;
```

Change password for admin:

```
UPDATE jos_users SET password=MD5(‘NewPassword’) WHERE username=’admin’;
```

And retry to acces again.

That’s all !!!

Answer (score 2):

Didn't seem to be a permission issue for me - tried giving the IIS_IUSRS account full control over everything in the web service, just to see if this was the cause.  The fix turned out to be recreating the application hosting the web service (i.e. the actual '.svc') in IIS

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I found a reference to an old domain account password in applicationHost.config under Virtual Directory defaults.

Answer (score 2):

so easy
find the file "applicationHost.config" in Windows -> System32 ->inetsrv -> config 
 1. backup "applicationHost.config" to another filename
 2. open file "applicationHost.config" clear data and save 
 3. open browser and call url internal website , finished.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a new, dedicated, user account... It is also worth checking that the password for that account has not expired, as that will also cause this 500.19 permissions issue.

Answer (score 2):

For ASP.NET Core websites, this generic error will also occur if you don't have the HttpPlatformHandler module installed, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33235848/33080) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.Net applications come pre-wired with a handlers section in the web.config. By default, this is set to readonly within feature delegation within IIS. Take a look in IIS Manager

1.Go to **IIS Manager** and click Server Name

2.Go to the **section Management** and click **Feature Delegation**.

3.Select the **Handler Mappings** which is supposed to set as **readonly**.

4.Change the value to **read/write** and now you can get resolved the issue

Answer (score 1):

I have just one more thing to say about this. With the same HTTP Error code, you can still have several different errors, as one of them has been posted here at the original question's description.
For example: after I've edited the `Web.Config` file of an ASP.NET project, I had

> Error Code       0x8007000d
>
> "Only one <configSections> element allowed. It must be the first child element of the root <configuration> element "

As it says, you must NOT insert your own XML stuff before the `<configSections>` part of the `Web.Config` file. After I've inserted my snippet after the end tag of `<configSections>`, it worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

My website's correct path was not specified in IIS.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is that,

1. just delete the corrupted folder.
2. Then re-create folder again.

> It seem that if the corrupted folder had been created before IIS
>   setup. If you created folder again, it will work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error after uninstalling Windows Server Update Services (WSUS) from the computer running IIS. Apparently uninstalling WSUS may break the IIS configuration on the server making other web application installed on the same server unavailable.

I found the solution for the problem [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/6f73e779-a1ce-4730-8a9f-a8d365209625/missing-2-dlls-for-iis-after-uninstalling-wsus-iis-broken?forum=winserveressentials).

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the value of the Key was incorrect in `Web.config` file:

```
    <defaultDocument>
        <files>
            <add value="Portal.htm" />
        </files>
    </defaultDocument>
```

when I change the value to "Portal.html" it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error after upgrading from Visual Studio 2013 to 2015. After a bit of searching and trying various fixes I found the problem can be resolved by removing the following from web.config:

```
<staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".less" mimeType="text/css" />
</staticContent >
```

Apparently staticContent is deprecated now?

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30050290/solved-visual-studio-2015-error-500-19)

**Edit 1**

This sort of prevented IIS from serving .json files when the program was deployed. If you do this you're supposed to re-add .json (application/json) to the mime types of your site in IIS. Here is some more info: http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/staticcontent/mimemap

**Edit 2**

I noticed that in my situation the above edit 1 solution only works temporarily. Once I redeploy the entry gets removed. So, I moved the mimeMap XML into `Web.Release.config`. Works fine now.

Answer (score -6):

1. Open IIS Manager from the start button
2. Double click on features delegate
3. Make all the properties read and write
4. go to ISPAI and remove all the permissions

If above not worked properly. Then, make sure that u have installed the visual studio first before installation of IIS,

For better solution uninstall visual studio and then again install first IIS properly then visual studio

Comment: down vote for suggesting installing visual studio on a web server

Comment: Uninstalling is not a solution.