# Cannot log on locally IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I resolve “HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error” on IIS7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929131/how-do-i-resolve-http-error-500-19-internal-server-error-on-iis7-0)

I am having the following problem when trying to access files from IIS Manager:

> There was an error while performing
>   this operation.
>
> Details:
>
> Filename:
>   \?\C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config
>   Line number:190 Error:Can not log on
>   locally to C:\SystemName\Site1 as user
>   c-c\c with virtual directory password

Comment: Can you provide the exact steps you took to reproduce this problem?