# 500.19 on IIS 7, Cant log on locally

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I don't know where sholud I ask this...

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4849941/684646) issue and I think the answer should me close to that, but seems that I can't still do this.

The funny thing is the same *(I think)* was done by me in another server w/ IIS 7 a year ago or so, without further trouble. It could be also that I don't remember so much of it.
I have an Apache server running on port 80 **(That can't be changed)**

### This is what I've done:

Integrated AppPool was an issue on the other server I've placed so I've tried to change the

- Default AppPool to a Classic .Net
- The WebApp Pool to a Classic .Net

The User is also mandatory on the Webservice so I'm placing a Service Account that impersonates for any anonymous (or not) user that might access so I have

- The ServiceAccount as Administrator of wwwroot and subfolders
- The ServiceAccount as Impersonated by default in the Default Web Site
- The ServiceAccount as Impersonated in every Web App I need
- Shared r/w the folder with the ServiceAccount

Also

- I've tested the access and both Authorization & Authentication works
  marvelous.
- I've restarted the app, the site and the IIS multiple times without
  success.
- Checked the Event Log without finding anything useful.
- Modified applicationHost.config getting into more troubles than solutions.

#### This is what I get when I try to see the App Settings at IIS7

> > --------------------------- Application Settings ---------------------------
>
> There was an error while performing this
>   operation.
>
> Details:
>
> Filename:
>   \?\C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config
>
> Line number: 165
>
> Error: Can not log on locally to %SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot as user
>   MyDOMAIN\MyUser with virtual directory password
>
> --------------------------- OK ---------------------------

#### This is what I see when I go to my page (an asmx)

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error The requested page cannot be
>   accessed because the related configuration data for the page is
>   invalid.
>
> Detailed Error Information Module IIS Web Core  Notification
>   Unknown  Handler Not yet determined
>
> Error Code 0x80070569
>
> Config Error Can not log on locally to C:\inetpub\wwwroot as user
>   MyDOMAIN\MyUser with virtual directory password
>
> Config File Unavailable (Config Isolation)
>
> Requested URL
>   http://localhost:8080/myApp/MyWebService.asmx
>
> Physical Path
>
> Logon Method Not yet determined
>
> Logon User Not yet determined

---

@Edit: 0x80070569 Drove me to see that The service account weren't logging on as a Service (as it should), nor as a Batch process.

It was a Security Setting that should be touched, a group policy object has to be set to the account (in the Example `MyDOMAIN\MyUser`). And that's an access that only the area of IT Security can grant.

### Even when this was changed the problem remained still.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It actually was a secpol.msc Policy What was blocking the web access. The ServiceAccount wasn't a Service one.

As in the edit that I posted IT Security gave me the privileges to set it a**s a Service Account**, but that alone just wouldn't do the trick.

In the Advanced Settings of the webSite

Physical Path Credentials Logon Type, Batch logonMethod was selected.

And the service account still wasn't with the privileges **to run as a Batch Process**.

#### And that was it.

Not only the service account, but also The *Run as a Batch Job* was necessary.

Comment: In `advanced settings` of the site, `Physical Path Credentials` was set to my user _(no idea why)_, but set to `Application user (Authentication pass through)` fixed the error. It started when my password in the Active directory was changed.

Answer (score 65):

The accepted answer didn't work for me.

But when I followed the below steps, my issue was resolved:

1. Go to your IIS manager.
2. Click on **Sites**
3. Right click on Default websites, Go to **Manage Website** and then click on
   **Advanced Settings**
4. Set your physical path credential to Specific user with credentials
5. Restart IIS

Note: You may also need to reenter the credentials in the application pool, if the system password has been changed recently.

Comment: This was our issue.  Would not have thought to change this.  We changed it to the "Application User (pass-through authentication)" option and got it working.

Comment: If you've already done this (like me), try re-entering your creds, especially if your enterprise environment regularly expires user passwords. It may be just trying to access the directory using your old creds.

Comment: @J.D. Mallen, yes I agree. You may also change the credential for the application pool as well, if the password is changed.

Comment: @SibeeshVenu Thank you so much for that. I pulled almost half of my hairs on this, you saved the remaining half.

Comment: @ZeeshanAjmal I hope it's grown back since :)

Answer (score 2):

Check the Password of your Application pool and application. Try clicking on the Test Settings to check the connection is proper

Comment: Worked for me, I had a AD authentication and my password expired and changed. When updated the application was throwing me this error page.

updated the password in IIS manager > Sites > My Site > Basic Settings > Connect as > Set credentials and that's it works like a charm!!

Comment: this was my issue. I updated the password of the user that is used for the "Physical Path Credentials" but I forgot to update any underlying application nodes and not just the website nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it causes by changing administrator password or changing user access.
After that application pool cannot access to local user.
One of the most stupid solution for this problem is remove website and application pool then make another website.
This solution helped me.

Comment: Totally agree with you, since you cannot manage the website you cannot manage it

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer didn't work for me.

But when I followed the below steps, my issue was resolved:

```
1. Go to your IIS manager.
2. Click on Sites
3. Right-click on Default Web Sites and select 'Basic Settings'
4. Select Classic .NET AppPool from the Application Pool drop down
5. Save and Exit
```

Everything went normal.

Answer (score 0):

None of the other answers solved the issue for me.

In the end, I had a re-create my site and app pool, which is far from ideal, but was the only solution that worked.

IIS must have been caching an old value that I couldn't find/clear.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this on my Windows 10 Pro / IIS web server, connected as localhost. I use IIS/localhost pretty much every day and have done for years, and I'd never seen this error message before.  I restarted the computer, and problem was gone immediately.  I have no idea what caused it to happen so suddenly, IIS/localhost was working fine earlier this morning, I didn't change any settings.  I was also getting similar error message when clicking on the website in Sites (the others were working fine).  I hope the restart fixes this problem for you as well.