# IIS 7 Permissions: How to set the correct permissions for a directory?

Tags: iis-7, directory-permissions

I have added my site to IIS 7 on my local machine. It has added fine but I can't get the permissions sorted on the folder. I get the following error when trying to browse the site:

HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions

Does anyone know what user I should add for the site to have correct permissions? 
I have tried:

Network Service
Local service
IIS_WPG
Administrator

and nothing works.

Thanks

Comment: This link should be useful. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/929131/how-do-i-resolve-http-error-500-19-internal-server-error-on-iis7-0

Comment: this link should be useful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/929131/how-do-i-resolve-http-error-500-19-internal-server-error-on-iis7-0

Answer (score 7):

Try to grant rights for `"IUSR","IIS_USERS"` with : Read,Execute,List.

Answer (score -6):

If you are using windows7 login as administrator and then run your iis local server program because in administrator mode you get the required iis permissions.

Steps to be followed are:

1. `START->ALL PROGRAMS->ACCESSORIES`
2. Right click on `"CMD"` and choose `"RUN AS ADMINITRATOR"`
3. On command prompt type `"net user administrator /active:yes"` and
   press"enter"
4. Restart system and click on adminitrator icon to login

Hope this may fix ur problem