# Unable to browse the asp.net web service (.asmx) using a browser after installing it on IIS

Tags: asp.net, web-services

**What**

I have created a very simple asp.net web service using .NET framework 3.5, its running fine when I tested it using the unit test. Now I want to host it on IIS, for that I have prepared a **web setup** project for it.

And have added the Content Files and Primary Output of the Web Service Project, after installing this and testing on iis.

**The Problem**

When I try to run the webservice using the browser I get the following error

***HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.***

**What have I tried ?**
I tried changing the security permissions of IIS_Users to allow read write all, 
tried changing the application pool version, for now I am trying with the default .NET framework 4 version.

**Codes** I think the web.config is the main culprit hence I am pasting it here...

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <configuration>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="cString" connectionString ="Data Source=VRAKSH-YASSER;Initial Catalog=uGraphDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=data#123;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
  </connectionStrings>    

    <!--<configSections>
      <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
        <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
          <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
          <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
            <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere" />
            <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
            <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
            <section name="roleService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingRoleServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
          </sectionGroup>
        </sectionGroup>
      </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>-->  
    <appSettings/>
    <!--<connectionStrings/>-->
    <system.web>

        <compilation debug="true" >
          <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
          </assemblies>
        </compilation>
    <!--
      The <authentication> section enables configuration 
      of the security authentication mode used by 
      ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
    -->
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <!--
       The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
       of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
       during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
       it enables developers to configure html error pages 
       to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.

       <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
         <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
         <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
       </customErrors>
    -->
      <pages>
        <controls>
          <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
          <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </controls>
      </pages>

      <httpHandlers>
        <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
        <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>
      </httpHandlers>
      <httpModules>
        <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      </httpModules>
    </system.web>
    <system.codedom>
      <compilers>
        <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" warningLevel="4"
                  type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
          <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
          <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
        </compiler>
      </compilers>
    </system.codedom>
    <!-- 
        The system.webServer section is required for running ASP.NET AJAX under Internet
        Information Services 7.0.  It is not necessary for previous version of IIS.
    -->
    <system.webServer>
      <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
      <modules>
        <remove name="ScriptModule" />
        <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      </modules>
      <handlers>
        <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
        <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory" />
        <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" />
        <remove name="ScriptResource" />
        <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode"
             type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode"
             type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
    <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding appliesTo="v2.0.50727" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
          <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions.Design" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
          <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>

</configuration>
```

**Browser Screenshot**

[image]

**IIS Version** : IIS 7 on windows 7

Comment: Check your application pool mode, is it running under `Classic` or `Integrated Mode` ?

Comment: Hi, I have tried both, shows the same error for both.

Comment: since HTTP Error 500.19 is server error, so can you kindly share an image of this error page IIS is displaying. Addtionally is it IIS6 or 7?

Comment: have updated the question, with these now

Comment: Try to delete the config file and add only the things you need like connectionstrings and then redo the normal procedure. Maybe that helps! I know not an elegant solution but maybe it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately had to reinstall IIS and then install the web service again, but this time I was required to enable Directory Browsing and the webservice now works fine !

Answer (score 0):

See the config Error Line on the error page.Since the application is using `WindowsAuthentication`, you user does not have rights on the directory where the application is deployed add the following in your config right after `<authentication>` tag, to deny anonymous users.

```
  <authorization>
     <deny users="?" /> 
     <allow users ="*" />
  </authorization>
```

Comment: and authentication ?, should I keep it as it is (which is Windows) ?

Comment: Yup, if it is to be accessed by AD users only. or you can remove it all together including `<authorization>` tag. But that shall make the web service accessible to anonymous users as well.

Comment: used the above authorization code and completely removed the authentication tag, still getting the same error :(

Comment: @Yasser, read again my comment I said if you remove `<authentication>` then remove `<authorization>` as well. and access it anonymously.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to grant permissions to the **App Pool User** to the `c:\inetpub\wwwroot\DiciplaAdministration` folder

Apparently it could also be related with the password of the **App Pool user**, double check the password is still valid

If this didn't solve your problem, try the following answers:

- [How do I resolve "HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error" on IIS7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/929131/1268570)

This article shows several situations where you could receive this error:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webtopics/archive/2010/03/08/troubleshooting-http-500-19-errors-in-iis-7.aspx

Comment: yes it is valid, other websites using the same application pool work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try Disabling

WSUS(Windows Server Update Services) compression. You can disable WSUS compression by running the following command on the server

> %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config
>   -section:system.webServer/httpCompression /-[name='xpress']