# Server Error: HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

Tags: .net, iis

I got this error when am trying to run my website on IIS...  i saw some of questions... actually i go through with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929131/how-do-i-resolve-http-error-500-19-internal-server-error-on-iis7-0)
but still same error..please give me some idea .. thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change anonymous authentication to use application pool.

Answer (score 0):

Remove folder with web site content from desktop folder to another path, ex. C:\publish, and grant permission read/write for application pool on this folder.