# Deploying MVC 4 application on IIS 7.5 Error HTTP 500.19

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, web-deployment

I am trying to deploy my asp.net mvc4 web app on IIS 7.5 under Windows 7 professional.
I have copied all the necessary files using publish method from Visual Studio 2010 express into folder D:\IIS\MyWebsite

This folder contains the typical structue MVC 4: folders App_Data, Content, Images, Views, Controllers, bin, App_GlobalResources, Scripts and some files at root like: Global.asax, Web.config.

I create a website with a name, let's me say as an example, MyFirstMVC on port 81 and associated to a custom app pool, let's say, MyAppPool (using ApplicationPoolIdentity) which is in integrated mode and using NET Framework 4 as my web app is developed in NET Framework 4.

When I run it below error is raised:

```
Error HTTP 500.19 - Internal Server Error
```

and above the example I can see in configuration source section below messages:

```
   49:     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
   50:     <handlers>
   51:       <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
```

I have tried to add IIS_IUSRS to my root folder 'MyWebsite' and give it full control permissions but it does not work. I have tried some things discussed here:

[How do I resolve "HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error" on IIS7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929131/how-do-i-resolve-http-error-500-19-internal-server-error-on-iis7-0)

Also I have observed that once opened inetmgr when I select the root node of the Connection tree on the left, then in the panel on the right, there is no ASP.NET group, only IIS and management so I am not sure it is normal, maybe is there something wrong with ASP.NET¿?

**SOLUTION:**
Finally, I have solved it by running following command as in internet information services ASP.NET was missed:

```
%windir%\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis.exe -i
%windir%\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```

in my case the path is pointing to Framework64 because I am running on a Windows 7 professional x86_64.

Comment: I have solved it by running the command above indicated in the udpated post.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue. MVC4 application with IIS7 under VS 2012 (windows 7 with 64 bit).I solved the issue with below command.
 Run -> CMD (administration mode)

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regiis.exe -i

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation but was receiving a 404 error. I'm running VS 4.5, IIS 7.5 and the website is MVC 4.5. I ran only the one line above which resolved my problem as well. thanks!

%windir%\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i

NOTE: i figured it was something like this since I received an error when trying to review ".NET Complication" within the webapp of IIS.