# Internal server error 500 after deleting wwwroot

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to upload my website , unfortunately i made a mistake,i delete  3 folders in my root directory i.e **logs** and **data** and **wwwroot**.So after recreating manually these folders i got this error:

```
500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.
```

How can i solve that ?any idea ?
Best regards

Comment: Try to set it's permissions to 777

Comment: @user1924402: 777 for asp.net?  Even if you mean "give everyone permission to everything" in the Windows sense, that is not a good idea.

Comment: Only for wwwroot, but you can try for all too, why not.

Comment: definitely sounds like a permissions issue. Review your iis configuration and windows event logs- they may give you pointers. A bit hard to give you more feed back as I am not sure exactly what you mean by root.

Comment: Did you create an empty `wwwroot` folder, or did you restore a backup?

Comment: @Gavin for example i have a folder mywebsite.com inside this folder i had these three folders that i said .and i deleted these 3 folders

Comment: @CodeCaster Yes i create an empty folder but after recreating i upload my files

Comment: [Check the actual error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640526/detailed-500-error-message-asp-iis-7-5), then [correct your permissions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/929131/how-do-i-resolve-http-error-500-19-internal-server-error-on-iis7-0).

Comment: @user1924402 i changed to 777 and it works ,any security problem ??????/

Comment: No, you don't have to worry about this.

Comment: @EA: Giving all permissions to every user is most certainly a security issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you've created the folder wwwroot in inetpub make sure the IUSR_computername has permission on this wwwroot folder and the files and folder under it. Also do verify the virtual directory in IIS, so that it is still pointing to the same folder.