# ASP.NET web.config error

Tags: asp.net

My ASP.NET web application works fine in VS. But when I try and deploy it on my webserver I get an error screen:

HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error. The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

```
Error Code 0x8007000d 
Config Error
Config File \\?\C:\Domains\leas****mail.com\web.config 

Config Source
-1:
0:
```

Any idea how I can debug this. Normally it would where in the web.config the issue is, but not in this case. I ran the file through an xml validator and there were no issues detected.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mind posting the web.config file?

Comment: It looks somewhat like the Config file can't be found...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I resolve "HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error" on IIS7.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/929131/how-do-i-resolve-http-error-500-19-internal-server-error-on-iis7-0)

Answer (score 0):

You are using a component that defines a new section in `web.config`. And that component is not installed on your server. I have this problem often with the URL Rewrite for IIS module (from [here](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)) or with the .NET Chart Controls (from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456632(VS.100).aspx)) for example.

Check your `web.config` section by section. You'll spot the culprit...