# Visual Studio 2015 Error 500.19

Tags: iis-7, visual-studio-2015

I have problem with opening project in VS 2015. In VS 2012, and VS 2013 is everythink ok. But when I start web application in VS 2015, I got error 500.19 while loding css and js files.

I know, that it shoud be because of permissions, so I set NETWORK, NETWORK SERVICE and IIS_IUSRS to read, write, modify on my project folder, but it did not help.

Have anyone idea?

Comment: 500.19 has many possible causes, so if you don't dig more from the error page itself, you won't get a detailed answer.

Comment: See: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/942055/ and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webtopics/archive/2010/03/08/troubleshooting-http-500-19-errors-in-iis-7.aspx

Comment: Please share the full error message

Comment: Finally I can handle with it. I just need to remove from my web.Config        
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".less" mimeType="text/css" />
    </staticContent >

Comment: Post that as answer and accept it. This is SO, so changing the title won't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally I can handle with it. I just need to remove from my web.Config

```
<staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".less" mimeType="text/css" />
</staticContent >
```

Comment: Nice find, mate. I guess `Static Content` has been deprecated in VS 2015 ASP.Net projects.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use your mimeMap instead of the one on IIS, just change your config file to remove the existing before adding yours:

```
 <staticContent>
     <remove fileExtension=".less" />
     <mimeMap fileExtension=".less" mimeType="text/css" />
 </staticContent >
```