# Why my wcf app cannot be hosted in windows server 2008 r2?

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, windows-services, windows-server-2008-r2

I have created a wcf application and actually I have not done anything. I have attached the automatically generated code to the server under the sites.

However, when i host the app it gives me the **HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error**. Moreover, it says cannot read config gile due to insufficient permission but permission is given to the every one I believe.

Therefore, what do you think I should do..? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for following links
1. [How do I resolve "HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error" on IIS7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929131/how-do-i-resolve-http-error-500-19-internal-server-error-on-iis7-0)

2. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/942055