# Running Kestrel yields empty browser

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

I've recently just upgraded `Visual Studio 2015` with `ASP.NET 5 beta8`, which causes the strange shift from the old listener over to this new '`Kestrel`' .. thing.

I've attempted to follow the instructions and get it to run, but I simply yield a console window that says...

> Hosting environment: Development
>
> Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
>
> Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.

Okay, so I navigate to `http://localhost:5000`, and ... nothing is there. My application doesn't run or anything.

I have tried to launch the default `ASP.NET MVC` sample project using Kestrel too, with the built in settings, and get the same result. I'm really unsure of what to do.

Here is what I've done so far...

I *have* it in my `project.json` file;

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-beta8",
},

"commands": {
   "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
},
```

My program was working fine on `beta7`, using the old listener; But now even that doesn't work suddenly since installing `beta8`. I'm at the hair-pulling stage of frustration over this forced change. I can't get it to run in `IIS` either.

Per request, this is my `Startup.cs` file;

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env, IApplicationEnvironment appEnv) {
    // Setup configuration sources.

    Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(appEnv.ApplicationBasePath)
        .AddJsonFile("config.json")
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .Build();
}

public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

// For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    // Add MVC services to the services container.
    services.AddMvc();

    services.UseCookieAuthentication(o => {
        //o.ExpireTimeSpan
        o.CookieName = "3b7eaa9c-decd-4c5d-83f9-01f1f11a6e22";
    });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app) {

    app.UseIdentity();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseMvc(routes => {
        // add the new route here.
        routes.MapRoute(name: "areaRoute",
            template: "{area:exists}/{controller}/{action}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
        );
    });
}
```

Comment: Please show your Startup.cs and did you create web.config with httpplatformhanler ?

Comment: I thought the web.config was only for running it in IIS?

Comment: "I thought the web.config was only for running it in IIS?" Yes

Comment: Alright, I thought this ..'Kestrel' thing was a standalone thing, like the old WebListener. Is it actually part of IIS? The information on the Visual Studio website didn't make it seem that way, and the built-in ASP.NET samples don't include a web config. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/10/15/announcing-availability-of-asp-net-5-beta8.aspx

Comment: Alright, I added my `Startup.cs` file to the question.

Comment: Some info about new Hosting model may read [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/364#issuecomment-148567294). I suggest you add logging in your application:

Comment: I suggest you add logging in your application: `loggerFactory.AddConsole(LogLevel.Debug)`, [see example](https://github.com/boyarincev/GetHabitsAspNet5/blob/master/src/GetHabitsAspNet5App/Startup.cs) and see what occur in logs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94794/discussion-between-boyarincev-and-ciel).

Comment: Also note http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33235257/iis-deployed-asp-net-5-beta-8-site-to-iis-gives-http-error-500-19-internal-ser/33237948#33237948 If you are using IIS and not IIS Express you have to install the HTTPPlatformHandler

Comment: Thank you, @Boyarincev for all of your help. After the things we did, it turned out to be a problem with a specific version of a library that was getting cached and not updating.

Comment: Hey @Boyarincev, can you post your stuff as an official answer so I can finally award credit?

Comment: Hello @Ciel, thank you very much for your concern!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That understand in which place the request pipeline problem arise, [enable logging](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/logging.html) in your application.

Comment: The problem was solved by logging and discovering that some libraries were not getting updated properly, yes!