# MVC 6 Hosted on IIS HTTP Error 500.19

Tags: iis, asp.net-core-mvc

Am getting HTTP Error 500.19 when accessing MVC 6 app in IIS on Windows 10.

In IIS I have set the App pool to 'No Managed Code'

The app is hosted in the root of a new Web Site.

I published the app using Visual Studio 2015 with the following settings.

Configuration : Debug
Target DNX Version: dnx-clr-win-x64.1.0.0-rc1-update1

The web.config is the boilerplate provided by Visual Studio

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <httpPlatform processPath="%DNX_PATH%" arguments="%DNX_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" startupTimeLimit="3600"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Any ideas what is going wrong?

Thanks

Mike

Comment: Check if there are any errors in ETW.

Comment: What do you mean by ETW?

Comment: Windows Event Tracing. Start->Run->eventvwr  and check Application logs.

Comment: Thanks, thought that was what you meant not heard it referred to as ETW before.

Comment: No errors in Application Log,

Comment: 500.19 error is due to invalid configuration (usually due to incorrect/unrecognised elements in web.config). Try adding app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage() in startup configuration if you haven't already added. That may give some clues.

Comment: Already have that in the Startup.cs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running MVC 6 Beta 8 application on IIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33255222/running-mvc-6-beta-8-application-on-iis)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Figured it out, I needed to install the httpplatformhandler 
http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/httpplatformhandler

Comment: I followed the steps here https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html I had exactly the same error on Windows Server 2012 IIS 8.5.   Then I set up HttpPlatform handler. And it worked. Thanks

Comment: FYI I installed httpplatformhandler but didn't work but after installing ASP.NET Core Module it started work.  My application is Asp.net core

Comment: Hi  powerfade917 ,  I have also same problem, I have created api project in asp.net core, and it works well on localhost. But when I have published my this .net api project, I am not be able to access it. Gives me this error message "HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error".    Does I missing something or Need to do any configuration in appsetting or web.config file ?

Comment: I installed the platform handler, hit CTRL+F5 in my browser and still I get the error.

Answer (score 18):

For RC2 and above, `HttpPlatformHandler` has been replaced by `ASP.NET Core Module`

Install the new module from [here](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817246).

The announcement can be found [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/164).

Comment: is that download x64?

Comment: AFAIK it should work on both x64 and x86. I am currently using it on various x64 machines.

Comment: This link provided did not help me, this page had the latest download and instructions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis?tabs=aspnetcore2x

Answer (score 3):

You have to install the "Hosting Bundle Installer". Without this, IIS doesn't understand routing and cannot host your application.

Go to microsoft site "https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/dotnet-core/runtime-2.1.0-rc1" and install "Hosting Bundle Installer":

[image]

Before installing this you have to install the right version of runtime:
https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/dotnet-core/runtime-2.1.0-rc1
Than install the right version of "Hosting Bundle Installer".

"Hosting Bundle Installer" is:
 .NET Core Windows Server Hosting bundle installs the .NET Core Runtime, .NET Core Library, 
and the ASP.NET Core Module. The module creates a reverse proxy between IIS and the Kestrel server on Windows platforms.