# Deploying ASP NET Core to IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, deployment, asp.net-core, publish

I've made a simple ASP.NET Core website based on tutorial on asp.net website [here](https://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/build-your-first-asp-net-application-with-asp-net-web-forms).

Now, I'd like to publish it on my other machine on the IIS.

I've followed the instructions on [this site](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html) but I just can't get it working...

I keep getting 500 Internal server error

Based on the logs in Event Viewer this is the culprit:

```
Failed to start process with the commandline 'dotnet .\MyWebApp.dll'. Error code = '0x80004005'.
```

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 2):

Had same error in a very similar situation. (New ASP.NET Core web api deployed to IIS)

Further investigation lead me to find that, in my case, 500.19 was the exact error.

Installing [ASP.NET Core Module](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817246) solved my problem.

reference: [MVC 6 Hosted on IIS HTTP Error 500.19](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35351198/mvc-6-hosted-on-iis-http-error-500-19)

Answer (score 2):

Returncode 500 points to a problem in starting your app.

In your publish / project folder try starting without IIS by typing:

dotnet yourapp.dll

Does this work? No: you have a problem in your project and the output should lead to your problem.

If it works properly: view "modules" in IIS Manager, is there following entry?

[image]

And another possibility: does your AppPoolIdentity-User has the appropriate right to access publish folder.

And you have "published"?