# HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error - Error Code 0x80070490 - IIS 7.5 ( Works on Azure )

Tags: iis-7.5, thinktecture, identityserver2

I am executing my code in the Azure emulators. The code I have built is Thinktecture's *IdentityServer2*. After the emulators start running and everything is ready I get an error when I fire the URL in the browser. There is another SO [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929131/how-do-i-resolve-http-error-500-19-internal-server-error-on-iis7-0/9495430#9495430) about this issue. But the solutions don't seem to apply to my *Web.Config*

1. There is no URL rewrite module rule
2. Default website in IIS manager has pass-through authentication. What is this ?
3. Gave full control to users to access wwwroot.
4. virtual folder>basic settings> Connect As > Path credentials  has pass-through authentication

What else should I do ?

**Web.Config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
<section name="system.identityModel" type="System.IdentityModel.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelSection, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
<section name="system.identityModel.services" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelServicesSection, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
<section name="thinktecture.identityServer.repositories" type="Thinktecture.IdentityServer.Configuration.RepositoryConfigurationSection, Thinktecture.IdentityServer.Core" />
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>
<!-- ............................................... -->
<!-- start of identity server relevant configuration -->
<thinktecture.identityServer.repositories configSource="configuration\repositories.config" />
<system.identityModel configSource="configuration\identity.config" />
<system.identityModel.services configSource="configuration\identityServices.config" />
<connectionStrings configSource="configuration\connectionStrings.config" />
<system.diagnostics configSource="configuration\tracing.config" />
<location path="account/certificatesignin">
  <system.webServer>
  <security>
    <access sslFlags="Ssl, SslNegotiateCert, SslRequireCert" />
  </security>
</system.webServer>
</location>
<system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
<diagnostics>
  <messageLogging logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true" />
</diagnostics>
</system.serviceModel>
<appSettings>
<add key="idsrv:CreateTestDataOnInitialization" value="true" />
<add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
<add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
<add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>

<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <remove name="RoleManager" />
  <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule"  type="System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
</modules>
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
</system.webServer>
 <system.web>
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" />
<globalization enableClientBasedCulture="true" uiCulture="auto" culture="auto" />
<profile configSource="configuration\profile.config" />
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/account/signin" />
</authentication>
<pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
<membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="ProviderDB" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="ProviderDB" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
<sessionState mode="Off"></sessionState>
</system.web>
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.3.0.0" newVersion="1.3.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlCeConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
  <parameters>
    <parameter value="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
  </parameters>
</defaultConnectionFactory>
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServerCompact.SqlCeProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact" />
</providers>
</entityFramework>
<system.data>
<DbProviderFactories>
  <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
  <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
</DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
</configuration>
```

**Error**

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Detailed Error Information:
Module     CustomErrorModule
Notification       SendResponse
Handler    Not yet determined
Error Code     0x80070490
Config Error       The configuration section 'system.webServer/httpErrors' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration
Config File    \\?\C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\dftmp\Resources\95c4e530-03a7-4e9f-b0c5-152a2cd71ccf\temp\temp\RoleTemp\applicationHost.config
```

**Note**

```
This error occurs when there is a problem reading the configuration file for the Web server or Web application. In some cases, the event logs may contain more information about what caused this error.
```

**Fix attempt 1**
Doesn't work.

```
     <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
    <!--Remove inherited 500 error page setting -->
    <remove statusCode='404' subStatusCode='-1'/> 
    <!--Override the inherited 500 error page setting with the 'My500.html' as its path-->
    <error statusCode='404' subStatusCode='-1' prefixLanguageFilePath='' path='/home/index' responseMode='ExecuteURL'/> 
    </httpErrors>
```

Comment: The error message is self explaining that some section declaration is missing. Find a healthy file to see how you should fix it.

Comment: AFAIK this is it from their Git.