# HTTP Error 500.19 Can't change IIS permisssions

Tags: asp.net, webforms

**The Issue**

I have cloned down an exiting web forms project and when I try to build, I get the error;

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
>   The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Below this error, the "Detailed Error Information:" section provided a config file path that seems to point to the correct place, accept to the machine of the previous contributor of the solution.

**Below is the approach I took to try resolving this issue**

Initially, from this, I tried finding out where this incorrect file path is coming from but came across nothing even vaguely relative so I tried googling the error itself.

I came across this question:
[How do I resolve "HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error" on IIS7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929131/how-do-i-resolve-http-error-500-19-internal-server-error-on-iis7-0)

An answer provided by Bruce mentioned to:

> "Check the directory and see if that user has appropriate rights to
>   it".

In an attempt to do this, I had a quick google and same across the following question: [The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216158/the-requested-page-cannot-be-accessed-because-the-related-configuration-data-for)

From intermension's answer, I gathered that it was "ApplicationPoolIdentity" that was not assigned the correct permissions so in ettempting to resolve this, I visited the following link. [IIS7 Permissions Overview - ApplicationPoolIdentity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334216/iis7-permissions-overview-applicationpoolidentity) 
I followed Jon Adams' steps successfully as shown here:

[image]

This was unsuccessful and I'm unsure of where to go now.

Thank in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow there steps:

1. Check which application pool your website is using 
   [image]
2. Change it to use ApplicationPoolIdentity if it is not.
3. Go to your website directory and search for Application Pool Identity user which has format IIS AppPool{AppPool Name} e.g. IIS AppPool\DefaultWebsite and give it read permissions

[image]

4. In IIS Manager select your website in the left pane and then in right pane double click the HandlerMappings icon to ensure that handlers list show up.