# 500.19 errors when hosting in IIS

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, iis

I have created ASP.Net application that inserts data into a SQL Server Express 2008 database through a web browser. Everything works perfect when I run it through localhost (CTRL F5). However when I try to set it up in IIS I get 500.19 errors. I have created test apps without SQL Server and they work fine. I have created test Apps with SQL Server and I get the same errors.

Comment: Look in the event log on the server Start > type "Event Viewer" and run it, then expand Windows Logs > Application. Look for errors that give you more detail.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I resolve "HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error" on IIS7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929131/how-do-i-resolve-http-error-500-19-internal-server-error-on-iis7-0)

Comment: i have seen this however my apps work without SQL Server connection

Comment: Make sure the user with with Installation is done on IIS  has rights for DB operations (CRUD for schema & data)

Comment: @PranavSingh You mean "rights", not "writes". "Rights" can be a synonym for "permission", while "writes" typically refers to recording data somewhere.

Comment: Agree Rights not writes, it was autocorrect type

Comment: Reveal the whole 500.19 error page please (mask out confidential info like IP or file path). There is a lot of causes, so only the page itself can tell more.