# Invalid Web.config Configuration Data

Tags: web-config, connection-string

I changed my `connectionStrings` section in `web.config` to `Integrated Security="True"` to hide username and password, but met the error:

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error The requested page cannot be
>   accessed because the related configuration data for the page is
>   invalid.

Before change:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add connectionString="Server=v-s1;Database=DB1;User ID=Admin;Password=AdminPW;Persist Security Info=True;Max Pool Size=200;Connection Timeout=60" name="MROConstr" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

After change:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add connectionString="Server=v-s1;Database=DB1;Integrated Security="True";Max Pool Size=200;Connection Timeout=60" name="V1Constr" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm tempted to mark "Closed/Duplicate", but look here:

> [How do I resolve "HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error" on IIS7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929131)
>
> Looks like the user account you're using for your app pool doesn't
>   have rights to the web site directory, so it can't read config from
>   there. Check the app pool and see what user it is configured to run
>   as. Check the directory and see if that user has appropriate rights to
>   it. While you're at it, check the event log and see if IIS logged any
>   more detailed diagnostic information there.

Specifically, it sounds like the user you're running as doesn't have permissions for one or more of the things it needs to do.

ALSO:

Be sure to consider the possibility that maybe you accidentally introduced a typo in a completely unrelated section of web.config.  Ideally, you can "diff" your current version with a backup web.config, to confirm the ONLY changes are those you DELIBERATELY made.

Good luck - and be sure to post back what you find!