# What does \\?\C: mean?

Tags: iis

Having IIS internal server errors 500.19, and seeing

```
Config File       \\?\C:\inetpub\wwwroot
```

as part of the error message, but I can't do a search for that first part as Google just ignores it...
What does

```
\\?\C:
```

mean?

PS - I'm explicitly asking about this symbol, and not how to resolve the error that is causing it.

Comment: The path might be irrelevant.  `\\?\` is sometimes use for network paths or Linux compatibility.  You are more likely to find a solution if you focus on the causes for a 500.19 error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929131/how-do-i-resolve-http-error-500-19-internal-server-error-on-iis7-0

Comment: Do you know which version of IIS you are using & the OS?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/file-path-formats Microsoft documents it and other variants.

Comment: @Lex-Li - this should be the answer. It gives exactly what I was looking for but did not know how to find. Thanks!