# IIS cannot access ASP.NET web.config file

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm a new forge user in BIM 360, my viewing model works well in VS but when it move to IIS, it shows error code about web.config file with error code

HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Detailed Error Information:
Module     IIS Web Core
Notification       Unknown
Handler    Not yet determined
Error Code     0x8007000d
Config Error
Config File    \?\C:\inetpub\wwwroot\BIM 360\web.config
Requested URL      http://www.surveyviewer.com:3000/
Physical Path
Logon Method       Not yet determined
Logon User     Not yet determined

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to forge, you may google based on your IIS version, there's already an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929131/how-do-i-resolve-http-error-500-19-internal-server-error-on-iis7-0) for IIS V7